# Does changing Django's TIME_ZONE have any negative effects?

Tags: python, django, time

1. I'm using Postgres
2. I have `USE_TZ=True`
3. I have `TIME_ZONE='America/Los Angeles'`
4. I am about to switch TIME_ZONE to UTC.

Will there be negative effects, gotchas, or anything I need to consider? Or will it just work since the date time is standardized? (I notice in my db rows that dates are stored with +08, which is indeed America/Los Angeles.)

The documentation mentions that if I use Postgres, I can swap `USE_TZ` freely, but doesn't mention changing `TIME_ZONE`.

Comment: Time zone support uses pytz: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Django always stores date time in UTC and now() always returns time in UTC or according to db.
so if you convert it using localtime() it will not affect how the value is stored.
**The thing which matters is how it is presented to user.**

Comment: So, does this mean I can indeed change `TIME_ZONE`?